# Does Directional Derivative Along a Particular direction Implies Continuity along that Direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We Know Existence of The Directional Derivative Doesn't Imply differentiability .

But I am Queried If It is Said the Func Has Directional Derivative Along Only One direction is it necessary that Function to be Continuos ALONG THAT DIRECTION

Comment: So this becomes a one-variable calculus question when you forget all other directions. What does one-variable calculus tell you?

Comment: One Variable Calculus Tells differentiability Implies Continuous.

Comment: Yup. Completely right.